# Probability that distance of two random points within a sphere is less than a constant

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

> Two points are chosen at random within a sphere of radius $r$. How to calculate the probability that the distance of these two points is $< d$?

My first approach was to divide the volume of a sphere with radius d by a sphere with radius r. But  it does not seem to work, at least not for $d > r$.

$$P = \frac{ 4/3 \pi  d ^3}{ 4/3 \pi  r ^ 3 }\tag{?}$$

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: What is $d$ here?  Diameter?  If so, then why do you refer to "radius d" and "at least not for for d > r"?

Comment: d is the distance between the two random points and a constant

Comment: Your first approach will not work when the first point is more than $r-d$ from the centre of the sphere

Comment: It also depends on how you randomize...

Comment: To clarify lets assume the random function is an equal distribution of points within the sphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you at three-dimensional integrals?
Let the first point be at $(0,0,z)$.  There are two spheres: One of radius $r$, centered at the origin, and one of radius $d$, centered at $(0,0,z)$.  I would let $r=1$ to remove one letter from your calculations.
The spheres' intersection is symmetric about the $z$ axis, which should help you calculate the volume of the intersection.  You rotate the intersection of two semicircles about the $z$ axis.
Once you have $P(z,d)$, you need to calculate the following.
$$P(d)=\frac{\int_0^1 z^2P(z,d)dz}{\int_0^1z^2dz}$$

Comment: Thanks for your fast and comprehensive response. My math is limited, so I have problems to understand the solution. However I have 3 questions:
1) The first point is at random coordinates within the sphere with radius r, not at (0,0,z)
2) I am looking for a solution for different r, so setting it to 1 does not help me.
3) How do you define P(z,d) ??

What I am really looking for, is a function P(r, d), which gives me the %-probability for any r, d > 0. Ideally something that I can calculate in Google sheets.

Comment: @bji74: $P(r,d)=P(1,d/r)$, so it suffices to solve the problem for $r=1$.

Comment: @bji74
(1) Pick the first point. Then change the coordinate system so that it is at (0,0,z).
(2) P(r,d) = P(1, d/r)

Comment: @StevenGregory: I suspect you intended to ping bji74?

Answer (score 1):

According to [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BallLinePicking.html), the density for $d$ is

$$
\frac{3d^2}{r^3}-\frac{9d^3}{4r^4}+\frac{3d^5}{16r^6}\;.
$$

Thus the cumulative distribution function that you're looking for is

$$
\int_0^d\left(\frac{3d'^2}{r^3}-\frac{9d'^3}{4r^4}+\frac{3d'^5}{16r^6}\right)\mathrm dd'=\left(\frac dr\right)^3-\frac9{16}\left(\frac dr\right)^4+\frac1{32}\left(\frac dr\right)^6\;.
$$

[Here's a plot.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%5E3%20-%209%2F16%20x%5E4%20%2B%201%2F32%20x%5E6%20for%20x%3D0..2)

Comment: The above formula for the CDF is worked out in an answer to the following question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3848889/probability-involving-two-points-inside-a-sphere question